# Replace elements of first array with elements of second array based on first occurence in Rust

Tags: algorithm, rust

I have two vectors:

[image]

Elements of second vector correspond to elements of first by the order of first occurence: if we had sixth element "00000" in first vector it would correspond to the third element "def" in second vec and so on. I have to replace all elements in first vector with their corresponding elements from second vector. What is a good algorithm for doing that? My initial idea looked like this:

```
    let mut vec1: Vec<&str> = vec!["12345","12345","11111","12345","11111"];
    let mut vec2: Vec<&str> = vec!["abc","xyz"];
    let mut counter: usize = 0;
    'outer: for i in 0..vec1.len() {
        for j in 0..i {
            if vec1[j] == vec1[i] {
                continue 'outer;
            }
        }
        let temp = vec1[i];
        for j in 0..vec1.len() {
            if vec1[j] == temp {
                vec1[j] = vec2[counter];
            }
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
```

Comment: The question is a bit too broad in its current form. Are you asking about an algorithm here? Have you tried implementing this yourself?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I thought about making a separate counter of first occurences, iterating over the first vector, scanning the vec from 0 to i every time, and if it's the first occurence of element i, then we replace all elements equal to vec[i] with vec2[counter], though it does seem expensive and bulky to me.

Comment: I suggest you turn this question into a question about the algorithm then, because this seems to be what you are struggling with. And add your algorithm idea (basically your comment) to the question as well, to give people context what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to store the associations between the two vectors in a separate hash map. You iterate the first vector, and look each element up in the hash map. If it's already in the hash map, you can take the value as the replacement. If it's not already there, you take the next available value from the second vector, add the new association to the hash map, and the replacement in the first vector.